# Message is stuck on ActiveMQ

Tags: java, jboss, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am using `JBoss-fuse-6.3`, with external `Apache-activemq-5.15.2.` I have bind 50 consumers on a queue, and on Active MQ portal in "Active Consumers" page, I have noticed that a message stuck in Number of pending message column its is not queuing mean while if another message arrived, that message easily dequeued.
[image]

Even when i tried to purge it give me the following error.

**error:**

[image]

and below are the logs of activemq.log

**activemq.log:**

```
2017-12-21 10:15:40,344 | WARN  |  | org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler | qtp1230701703-382
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Possible CSRF attack
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)[tomcat-servlet-api-8.0.24.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)[tomcat-servlet-api-8.0.24.jar:]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.apache.activemq.web.AuditFilter.doFilter(AuditFilter.java:59)[activemq-web-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.apache.activemq.web.filter.ApplicationContextFilter.doFilter(ApplicationContextFilter.java:102)[file:/opt/apache-activemq-5.15.2/webapps/admin/WEB-INF/classes/:]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:542)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:542)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:258)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_151]
```

I am not able to identify why its happening. Prefetch limit of each consumer is 1 and I am 100% sure that the content of each message same. message is in XML format. Message insertion is done from Apache Camel.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the reason for the exception and message not dequeuing is different.

The exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Possible CSRF attack
```

is caused due to some missing security setting in ActiveMQ, you can refer 
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/MB-670?_sscc=t  for more details

Hope it helps!

Good luck!